# Swift Cast from 'UIViewController?' to unrelated type 'TableViewCell' always fails

Tags: swift, uitableview

I implemented a `secondtableview` in `firsttableview -> firsttableviewcell.`

I want to access the function of `firsttableviewcell` in `secondtableviewcell`.

I have implemented a function that accesses `parentView (firsttableviewcell)` and an error occurs.

In `UiView` :

```
var parentViewController: UIViewController? 
{
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

In `secondtableviewcell` :

```
if let myViewController = self.parentViewController as? firsttableviewcell
{
    myViewController.getNextPage()
}
```

In `firsttableviewcell` :

```
class firsttableviewcell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    ...
}
```

And I had an error in the `secondtableviewcell`.

> Cast from 'UIViewController?' to unrelated type 'FirstTableViewCell' always fails

How do I get Cell view when I import a parent view?

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: I wonder how to approach because the top view is uitableviewcell.

Comment: so you have a tableView that contains the first cell as a tableView ?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: You are going to cast a **controller** to a **cell** which is not possible. By the way please name classes with a starting uppercase letter. This avoids confusion.

Comment: Ok. I'll search how to cast UITableviewcell.

Comment: The issue is not with your casting, you are trying to cast a VC object to tableViewCell which is always going to fail.

you should look at Delegation, beacuse the way you are trying to achieve the functionality is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do seems unclear, but 
you are unwrapping  `self.parentViewController` then you are casting it `as? firsttableviewcell` a `UIViewController` can't be casted as a `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access **firsttableviewcell** from **secondtableviewcell** by iterating all the superViews of **secondtableviewcell** and checking the class of that superview, you can get it from the below mentioned code.

```
func getFirstTableViewCell() -> UITableViewCell? {
        var view = self.superview
        while (view != nil && view!.isKind(of: UITableViewCell.self) == false) {
            view = view!.superview
        }
        return view as? UITableViewCell
}
```

> Code in **secondtableviewcell**:

Note: I added a button action and clicking on it will give you firsttableviewcell

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        getSuperCell()
}
```